# Add new currency to Yosemite Spotlight

Tags: macos, spotlight

Is it possible to add new currency to the spotlight currency conversion?
I'd like to have UAH (Ukrainian Hryvna) in my spotlight.

Comment: Any update on this maybe? Adding a custom currency to Spotlight...

Answer (score 1):

No, this is currently not possible. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Comment: I've provided feedback. And hope apple will fix it soon.